# RDS instance CPU utilization

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-rds

My amazon mysql large RDS instance's CPU utilization is going very high (about 70%) without any genuine reason. How to find which query or process is harming my instance?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The standard method is to examine `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or `SHOW ENGINE InnoDB STATUS` to see what's going on.

You are using InnoDB, right?

Comment: thanks @tadman, I am using InnoDB. This is happen on my live server, and at mid-night. so, how can i check this. means do manually or any utility/tool available? Can I get that query/process which is harm my CPU?

Comment: You can run a script to capture the results of those two commands and schedule it in a `cron` job somewhere.

Comment: really don't know how do I do this? do you have any script (or any tutorial). and what is cron job? I am new in mysql and RDS.

Comment: First step is making a shell script with the correct `mysql` client command-line arguments to log in: `--user=... --password=...` and so forth, then bundling that up in a script you can run in cron. That's another question though.

Comment: one more question. which transaction bring CPU utilization high? means If I insert, update, delete in table then CPU become high or when I fired select statement? and when IO used?

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to measure which query is causing the CPU load. You'd have to try each one in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be due to the autoback feature RDS provides. I think AWS RDS does an automatic back up around midnight everyday, you must factor this into your calculations