# RDS High CPU utilization

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-web-services, innodb, amazon-rds

I am facing high CPU utilization issue, is too many concurrent `create temporary table` statement cause high CPU utilization?

Is there any query through that we can capture queries which causing high CPU utilization?

**Variable we set:-**

`tmp_table_size = 1G`

`max_heap_table_size = 1G`

`innodb_buffer_pool_size = 145 G`

`innodb_buffer_pool_instance = 8`

`innodb_page_cleaner = 8`

**Status Variables:-**

```
        mysql> show global status like '%tmp%';
    +-------------------------+-----------+
    | Variable_name           | Value     |
    +-------------------------+-----------+
    | Created_tmp_disk_tables | 60844516  |
    | Created_tmp_files       | 135751    |
    | Created_tmp_tables      | 107643364 |
    +-------------------------+-----------+
mysql> show global status like '%innodb_buffer%';
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                         | Value                                            |
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status        | Dumping of buffer pool not started               |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status        | Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170917 19:11:45 |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status      |                                                  |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data         | 8935464                                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data         | 146398642176                                     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty        | 18824                                            |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty        | 308412416                                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed      | 122454921                                        |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free         | 188279                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc         | 377817                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total        | 9501560                                          |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd     | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead         | 585245                                           |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted | 14383                                            |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests      | 304878851665                                     |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads              | 10537188                                         |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free          | 0                                                |
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests     | 14749510186                                      |
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Created_tmp_tables likly causes the high CPU usage indeed.. but this question should be on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You could reprogram your (php) code so you fire a `show session status like '%tmp%'` before and after your query then you can find out what queries need to create a temp table if you log the queries and the status.. you most likly want to optimize those qeuries.

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27897/struggling-to-debug-high-cpu-usage-on-amazon-rds-mysql-instance and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053980/rds-instance-cpu-utilization.

Comment: Let's step back and look at a common query.  Almost always "high CPU" is caused by an inefficient query -- poor index, poor formulation of the query, etc.  Lots of tmp tables is not the evil itself.  Those counters are useless without knowing `Uptime`.  Also, do you have `TEXT` columns?

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1 -
  show processlist 
  Find is any process is locking table if yes than change it to myisam.
- Step 2 -
  Check Ram and your db size
- Step 3 -
  Explain complex queries and check if file sort or maximum number od rows are getting scan remove it either by making table flat , not more than 4 sub queries
- Step 4 -
  Use of joins efficiently